# Logged multiple user in the same application using Dropbox

Tags: swift, cloud, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working on an application which use the Dropbox API and I need to allow to link multiple accounts to the Dropbox acccount.
I made the application setup and I'm able to connect with one user in this moment.

```
@IBAction func linkButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared, controller: self, openURL: {(url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)})
}
```

I followed the Dropbox API suggestion in order to allow multiple user linked to the application (SwiftyDropbox):
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#multiple-dropbox-user-case

I tried to use their recommendation but without any result.
Can you help me in this case to allow link multiple account to the Dropbox ?

Kind regards!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "without any result"? What didn't work exactly? Please share any unexpected error you got, or show what didn't do what you expected.

Comment: By the way, you mentioned you're using the SwiftyDropbox SDK, but you linked to the Objective-C SDK. Here's the correct link for this for SwiftyDropbox: https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#multiple-dropbox-user-case

Comment: I followed the steps described into the Multiuser section and I couldn't log in. I harcoded the data for tests ..

Comment: @IBAction func link2ndAccountBuutonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
//        DropboxClientsManager.setupWithAppKeyMultiUser("1to5gbhlsaiwhcz", tokenUid: "xN_FC80T6UoAAAAAAAAAKP6x8mK-gsNMRfwdFixJ7eBhOqEqY4GAuNM0gW_c0UOB")
        
//        DropboxClientsManager.setupWithAppKey("1to5gbhlsaiwhcz")
    }

Comment: I made test with both methods... I try to find a demo which describe the flow in order to link a second link to the dropbox application.

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean when you say you "couldn't log in". Please update your question to show exactly what didn't work as expected.

Comment: Also, `tokenUid` is supposed to be [the user ID](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/blob/ebc42211d1a7bc1ae84d11940fbef9c93809d13d/Source/SwiftyDropbox/Shared/Handwritten/OAuth.swift#L304), not the access token string itself. And for the sake of security, you should revoke that access token since you posted it publicly: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#auth_token/revoke

Comment: I read the steps from the Multiplier-dropbox-user-case and what I wrote earlier I tried. All the informations from your link and try again.